# mathematical model of one electrostatic problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I am trying to find direct-current electric field in a specific domain: it is a brick made from a low-conductive material with a number of more conductive inclusions of different shapes - spheres, cylinders, and more complicated ones - composed of the simplest shapes.
There are 2 plane electrodes attached to the top and bottom faces of the brick. The electric potential on the top electrode is equal to $1~(V)$, the potential on the bottom electrode is $0$.

[image]

Here is a notation:
$\Omega_1$ - low-conductive part of the domain (main medium),
$\Omega_2$ - conductive inclusions,
$\partial\Omega_{top}$ - top face of the domain,
$\partial\Omega_{bottom}$ - bottom face of the domain,
$\partial\Omega_{side}$ - side faces of the domain,
$\Gamma_{12}$ - inner boundary between inclusions and brick.

The inclusions are distributed and rotated inside the brick randomly, therefore I am solving the problem numerically. And I am using finite element method for that. Consequently I need to formulate the problem as a boundary value problem governed by partial differential equation.

I see 3 different cases of how inclusions can be distributed:

1. All inclusions are fully inside the brick.
2. Some inclusions touch the top or the bottom face of the brick and therefore touch the electrode.
3. Some inclusions compose a conductive cluster from the top face to the bottom one, therefore there is a channel between electrodes.

Perhaps the 2nd case is the particular case of the 3rd one. So I am considering only 1st and 3rd problems.

What is common for these problems:

1. In both cases the electrostatic potential distribution is described by Laplace equation
   $$ \operatorname{div} (\rho^{-1} \operatorname{grad}         \phi) = 0, $$
   where $\phi$ is a scalar potential $(V)$, $\rho$ is an electrical resistivity $(Ohm \cdot m)$.
2. There is no current flowing through the side faces of the domain (homogeneous Neumann boundary condition)
   $$ \rho^{-1} \left. \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} \right|_{\partial\Omega_{side}} = 0 $$
3. Although I may be wrong here, I suppose that there is no current flowing through the inner boundaries (between inclusions and main medium)
   $$ \rho^{-1} \left. \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} \right|_{\Gamma_{12}} = 0 $$

In the first case (when inclusions are inside the brick) I am imposing non-homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions on the top and bottom faces (according to the voltage on the electrodes):
$$ \phi|_{\partial\Omega_{top}} = 1 $$
$$ \phi|_{\partial\Omega_{bottom}} = 0 $$

I think that in this case the mathematical model correctly describes the physical problem, and can be used to find the electric field.

But what if there is a conductive cluster that touches both electrodes?

Consider a simplified case with a brick and a cylinder inside it.

[image]

The top and the bottom faces consist of 2 subdomains - one from the brick, and another from the cylinder.
$$ \partial\Omega_{top} = \partial\Omega_{top\_brick} \cup \partial\Omega_{top\_cylinder}$$
$$ \partial\Omega_{bottom} = \partial\Omega_{bottom\_brick} \cup \partial\Omega_{bottom\_cylinder}$$

If I define non-homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions on both subdomains (like in the 1st case considered above)
$$ \phi|_{\partial\Omega_{top\_brick}} = \phi|_{\partial\Omega_{top\_cylinder}} = 1 $$
$$ \phi|_{\partial\Omega_{bottom\_brick}} = \phi|_{\partial\Omega_{bottom\_cylinder}} = 0 $$

I feel that I am solving 2 separate independent problems - one in the brick, and another in the cylinder. And whatever physical properties I define in the brick and cylinder, the electric field always changes linearly from the top electrode to the bottom one. Don't you think it is wrong? I feel that I am missing something in the statement (mathematical model) of this problem - maybe there are some assumptions that I didn't make. What should I add to (or remove from) my model to get the right (from physical point of view) solution of the last problem?

To be more specific talking about physical properties of the media considered in the problems, I suppose that "conductive material" has $\rho = 10^{-3}~(Ohm \cdot m)$ and "low-conductive material" has $\rho = 10^3~(Ohm \cdot m)$.

I have already asked the similar question on SciComp SE. Here is the [link](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8446/boundary-conditions-for-electrostatic-problem) if it can help.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS, thanks for editing, especially for correction of a TeX-code of a formula. But I think that replacing tag "mathematical physics" with "homework" is a bit over the top. Could you comment?

Comment: The "homework" tag isn't really   meant to mean "real homework".  It generally means questions related to solving problems, or stuff that arises in an educational context. And "mathematical physics" is not the right word here. If you click on the tag, it will lead you to it;'s tag wiki, that defines it as the rigorous  prescription of physics.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS, well, let it be.

Comment: @DiMension10: After reading the tag wiki for "homework", I see that it does provide for Questions that are not literally homework, but "of primarily educational value" and "where it is preferable to guide the asker to the answer rather than giving it away outright."  I cannot see the point of labeling this particular Question so, esp. given the lack of any ready suggestions about how to proceed.